# HTML borders not the same length

Tags: html, border, css

I have this list of salons and each has a dotted border on the right hand side. Some of these borders stop before others, is there any way to make them all the same length? (ideally so they reach the footer)
All salons are in this HTML (the information is just different):

```
<div class="salons">
  <h1><a href="salonpage.php?salonid=1">Urban Bliss</a></h1>
  <p> 15 Headingly Lane,
    LS6 1BL.
    0113 278 1572</p>
</div>
```

and the CSS is as follows:

```
.salons {
font-family:"Century Gothic";
width:248.5px;
max-height:inherit;
float:left;
padding-left:5px;
border-right:1px dotted #FFB6D7;
padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

[image: This is a photo of the issue]

Comment: You need to set a fixed height or `100%`.

Comment: I would say have a fixed height. Also @JoshPowell will `100%` work?

Comment: i added height: 100%; into my css but it hasnt solved the problem unfortunately

Comment: @JoshPowell Im clearly high it would work.

Comment: lol :] It just needs a height on it's parent to have `height: 100%;` work.

Answer (score 4):

Okay you need to give it's parent a fixed size, of the longest one, and then add `height: 100%;` to the children.

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 190px;
}

.salons{
    font-family:"Century Gothic";
    width:248.5px;
    height:100%;
    float:left; /* the reason the parent needs a fixed height is due to the float */
    padding-left:5px;
    border-right:1px dotted #FFB6D7;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3KXSH/)

Comment: thank you! can you explain what a parent is though? sorry very new to all of this!

Comment: No need to be sorry! A parent is an html element that contains other tags. The class name does not need to be parent, what this does is the `parent` is containing the class `.salons` which therefor are a child of that parent. Since the parent has those styles the children can now inheret what 100% would be of the parent. Without a parent the 100% would not work since there is nothing to compare 100% to.

Comment: @user3095683 I made this fiddle to show you how 100% height works with it's parent. In this http://jsfiddle.net/5xtB4/ the `div` has no parent with styles so the height 100% does nothing. In this http://jsfiddle.net/5xtB4/1/ I added height and width to be 100% on the `html, body` which contain that `div`. Now you can see how the `div` is inheriting it's parents size. Hope this helps, if this was the answer you can always mark it as the accepted answer. :]

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because some of the box heights are less than the tallest. To fix this, just add a fixed height to all of the divs in the css. 
For example:

```
height:200px;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Because they have different `height` (based on it's content)...
You can try giving a fixed height to the `.salons` `class`
or...
a 100% and a fixed height to the container.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `height`, `min-height` and `max-height`

```
.salons {
  /* other style */
  height: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Don't need to fix any height I think just make the parent `display:table;` and make the class salons `display:table-cell;`

To check how this thing work try the below given HTML and CSS

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2<br />2</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul { display:table; list-style:none; }
ul li { display:table-cell; padding:10px; border-right:1px solid red }
```